# Concurrently fill a dictionary with HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnet-httpclient, parallel.foreach

I have a .net site in which I'm trying to get the results of several web service calls, to be shared among several dropdownlist elements, in a parallel fashion.  My problem is all of the dropdowns end up having the same values, or some have the same values with one having different values (probably not the correct ones).  How can I fix this to get these things in parallel?

***Code Updated:***

```
using (HttpClient hc = new HttpClient())
{
    hc.BaseAddress = new Uri(CatalogUri);
    hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/jsonp"));
    // request for standard options
    HttpResponseMessage stdResponse = hc.PostAsJsonAsync(CatalogSearchOptionPath, searchmeta).Result;
    List<string> keynames = {"Key3", "Key2","Key1"};
    ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>> customOptions = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>();

    IEnumerable<Task<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>>> tasks = from key in keynames select GetCustomOptionList(key, hc, searchmeta);

    customOptions = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>(await Task.WhenAll(tasks));

    if (stdResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string g = stdResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        stdOptions = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SearchOption>>(g);
        //options = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SearchOption[]>().Result.ToList();
    }
}
```

Async method for doing the requests:

```
private async Task<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>> GetCustomOptionList(string key, HttpClient client, SearchMetadata sm)
{
    sm.OptionFieldName = key;
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(CatalogSpecificOptionPath, sm);
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(key, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(result));
}// end task
```

Comment: Have you tried to create `HttpClient(hc)` in `Parallel.ForEach` loop?

Comment: Not as of yet, but wouldn't that defeat the purpose of using()?

Comment: Matt, move it also into the loop :)

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Are you sure the results are wrong? If they are, in which step do they become wrong?

Comment: @svick there is a whole other program besides this.  My code above IS the "step in which they become wrong."  I'll say the part starting with `stdResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode` is working as expected.

Comment: Don't move the creation of the HttpClient into the loop, as you will kill perf.  Disposing HttpClient forcibly closes the underlying TCP connection.  My suggestion would be to replace the .Result with a ContinueWith

Comment: If calling async methods in a Parallel.Foreach is a problem then just use a regular foreach, stick the resulting tasks in an array and then do a Task.WhenAll to wait for them to complete.

Comment: @DarrelMiller My answer was just for debugging, you're totally right that instantiating all those clients would be expensive. `.ContinueWith` is a better answer, since presumably it would keep each `HttpResponseMessage` distinct in its own context instead of changing the reference to whatever comes back first from the client.

Comment: @DarrelMiller, welegan,  I tried moving the client creation inside the loop and it didn't really change anything.  I've kept looking around and saw other people mention Task.WhenAll but haven't tried that yet as it seems to complicate the code a little more (and it was the end of the day).  .ContinueWith was how I started out because of the examples on MSDN/TechNet and elsewhere, but I think I had a problem with debugging that.  I'll give each of these things a shot.

Comment: `.ContinueWith` did not work out - there was an error saying the task was cancelled. Or at least that is how it went with the `Parallel.ForEach` loop.  Would a regular foreach be "parallel" using `.ContinueWith`?

Comment: Regular `foreach` suffered the same issue with `.ContinueWith`.  I'm going to try now with `.WhenAll` and the task list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I have gotten this to work so all my dropdowns have the correct values.  It FEELS like I'm doing something wrong with it, but it works and I'm on a deadline so it will have to do for now.  Maybe later I'll be able to get a better solution.  Maybe someone on StackOverflow will provide a better solution - we'll see!

```
/// Do Stuff in Async method
using (HttpClient hc = new HttpClient())
{
    hc.BaseAddress = CatalogUri;
    hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(HttpJsonHeader);

    if (Session["StandardSearchOptions"] == null || rebindStandardOptions)
    {
        // request for standard options
        HttpResponseMessage stdResponse = hc.PostAsJsonAsync(CatalogSearchOptionPath,
                                                 searchmeta).Result;

        IEnumerable<Task<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>>> tasks = 
                               from key in keynames 
                               select GetCustomOptionList(key, hc, searchmeta);

        customOptions = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>(await
                                                    Task.WhenAll(tasks));

        if (stdResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string g = stdResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            stdOptions = Newtonsoft.Json
                          .JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SearchOption>>(g);
        }
        Session["StandardSearchOptions"] = stdOptions;
    }
    else // only rebinding the custom options
    {

        IEnumerable<Task<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>>> tasks = 
                                                  from key in keynames 
                                                  select GetCustomOptionList(key, hc,
                                                                         searchmeta);

        customOptions = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>(await 
                                                              Task.WhenAll(tasks));
    }
}
/// Do other stuff in Async Method
```

Async method for doing the individual custom searches:

```
private async Task<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>> GetCustomOptionList(string key,
                                    HttpClient client, SearchMetadata sm)
{
    sm.OptionFieldName = key;
    var response = await HttpClientExtensions
                      .PostAsJsonAsync(client, CatalogSpecificOptionPath, sm)
                      .Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(key,
                Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert
                            .DeserializeObject<List<string>>(response));
}// end task
```

Answer (score 1):

One reason why this could be happening is the fact that there is one `HttpClient` instantiated on the outside of the loop. Since the loop then uses `HttpClientExtensions.PostAsJsonAsync` which takes in the `hc` variable, then it's possible that the repeated values for the keys in the `ConcurrentDictionary` is the result of `response` being overwritten as the first call to return from the `HttpClient` within all of the loop iterations. This would depend on the implementation of `PostAsJsonAsync`, but one easy way to test would be to instantiate a new `HttpClient` in the loop and see if that fixes it.

Edit: Beware of using `.Result`, though it may not be the cause of your issue.

> “Async all the way” means that you shouldn’t mix synchronous and asynchronous code without carefully considering the consequences. In particular, it’s usually a bad idea to block on async code by calling Task.Wait or Task.Result. This is an especially common problem for programmers who are “dipping their toes” into asynchronous programming, converting just a small part of their application and wrapping it in a synchronous API so the rest of the application is isolated from the changes.

[source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Lastly, if you end up achieving only a 2x speedup when this is all working, consider tweaking this web.config tag:

[Sytem.NET MaxConnection property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tkaca2y.aspx)

Comment: Using `await` inside `Parallel.ForEach()` is a bad idea and won't work as expected. Using `SomethingAsync().Result` is often a bad choice, but I think it's reasonable here, since there is no synchronous version of the method (I think). In any case, I don't see how could this fix the issue.

Comment: Good point about await in Parallel.ForEach(), I guess I didn't read the question carefully enough. The use of `.Result` was just a very common cause of error so I thought it was likely that.

Comment: You're probably right about the cause now. `HttpClient` is not thread-safe, so using it from multiple threads like this is certainly wrong.

Comment: @svick HttpClient is thread safe.  There is no problem using it from multiple threads.